# Allowing to request hosts without HTTPS

Tags: jquery, office365, excel-addins

I have created my own office 365 excel web add-in and want to show some external data there. I have another server which runs on HTTP but not HTTPS.  I am trying to do jquery ajax call to my server, but I am getting access denied error.

`{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"Error: Access is denied.\r\n"}`

According to some of my research, add-ins require to use only HTTPS for security issues. I have tried with other servers which runs on HTTPS and it is working perfectly.

Is there any workaround to temporary allow using HTTP for remote calls? Any ideas?

Comment: I would guess this is because of security - probably you'll need to transmit some authentication data in order to verify your request, and you really don't want to be doing that in the clear over HTTP. And if it's not that, at the very least you don't want to be sending your / your customer's business data around the internet unencrypted either. Best to make your site support HTTPS. It needn't cost money, if that's an issue - there are one or two services out there which provide free SSL certificates.

Comment: P.S. The other possible reason for this kind of error could be CORS restrictions. Without seeing more detail it's impossible to know.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson. Sure. The add-in is not in production yet, so we are not dealing with security issues and our server is on its way to support SSL. I was wondering if with excel add-in's configuration, is it possible to allow using HTTP requests?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way, no. Your browser and operating environment doesn't know it's not a production app. But also the best way to prevent unexpected problems when you go into production is to mirror the production environment as closely as possible in your dev/test environments. So putting SSL into this environment would be a sensible step towards that in any case.